# Cast Const Integer to Bigint in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, type-conversion

I'm getting the below error while running the below script.  My goal is to create a function in Postgres to return 1 as a bigint.  Help please!

hashtagpostgresnoobie

> ERROR:  function result type must be bigint because of OUT parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetNumberOne(
    OUT numberone bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$

    SELECT CAST(1 AS BIGINT) AS "NUMBERONE";

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You've suddenly encountered the feature ) Record needs two and more fields. So when you have only one out variable, then result must be scalar.

So, you can simply do what compilers ask )

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetNumberOne(
        OUT numberone bigint)
      RETURNS bigint AS
    $BODY$

        SELECT CAST(1 AS BIGINT) AS "NUMBERONE";

    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

plpgsql example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NumberOne()
      RETURNS bigint AS
    $BODY$
      DECLARE num bigint;
      BEGIN
        num := 1;
        RETURN num;
      END
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
      select * from NumberOne()
```

Comment: I apologize for my slowness, but could you please be more specific?  I had a hard time following that.  I've been using Postgres for all of about 10 hours now.  :/

Comment: I'll provide exact snippet after lunch )

Comment: It turned out to be simpler. Take a look.

Comment: Holy fantastic answers, Batman!  I'd upvote more than once if I could.